# display number with commas and decimal points

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to display a number with commas and decimal point

> CASE1 : example if the number is 3494309432324
>
> display as 34,94,30,94,32,324 but not 34,94,30,94,32,324.00

Case 2 : if the number has decimal values them till 2 decimal points and with commas

> display as 12,22,222.32

currently i do this for 2 decimal places but i dont get the commas

> `Label9.Text = sisRatio.ToString("#0.00");`

any suggestions..

thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity: Why do you want to separate the number after *two* digits (rather than after *three* digits)?

Comment: @Heinzi: I believe that the question is related to the way numbers are represented in India.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you want the usual 3 numbers then a comma, I think this will do what you need:

```
Label9.Text = sisRatio.ToString("#,##0.##");
```

One slight issue with this is that it will only one decimal place if the second one would be 0

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
Label9.Text = sisRatio.ToString("##,0.00");
```

I'm assuming that you want to separate groups by thousands and not by hundreds as in your question. Note that this will use the localized separator for the current culture.

Comment: @Jamie, there are some cultures that uses 2-digit grouping, and some (as in the OP example) that uses 3 digits for the right-most group and then 2-digit groups after that. This info can be fetched from `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes`.

Comment: @Frederik: Thanks for pointing that out. I've built a few locale aware apps and hadn't run across that before. I wonder if grouping my salary in 2-digit groups would make me feel better about the amount?

Answer (score 4):

The following approach should give you what you are looking for,:

```
double d = 123456789.1;
string format = d.ToString().IndexOf(NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator) >=0 ? "#,##0.00" : "#,##0";
Console.WriteLine (d.ToString(format));
```

This will also work for cultures that does not have 3-digit groups.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are two ways to answer this question:

1. An algorithmic answer which gives the number in the specified format i.e. 2 digits between the commas.
2. Working out that this is a locale-relative solution, since I can't get any of the given ToString() suggestions to work on my PC.

This question caught me out initially as it's not as easy as it looks.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
Label9.Text = sisRatio.ToString("#,0.00"); //changed from "#0,0.00" to "#,0.00"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
    Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = New CultureInfo("hi-IN")
    End Sub
```

and .....

```
Private Sub txtData_Leave(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtData.Leave
        If IsNumeric(txtData.Text) Then
            Dim xData As Integer = txtData.Text
            txtData.Text = xData.ToString("##,0.00")
        End If
    End Sub
```